# Texture transparency brush with OpenGL ES on iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, brush

I am new to OpenGL and trying to implement an eraser brush which will erase a texture with brush stroke to reveal the background of the opengl view, by adjusting the alpha value at the the brush stroke. the OpenGL view's opaque property is set to NO.

I am using the Apple's GLPaint as a starting point. The brush I am using is a texture whose center is alpha zero with radially fading alpha to 1 at the circuler edges.

I use `glColorMask(0,0,0,1)` to draw only on the alpha channel.

Now, the problem is with the blend function. If I use `glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA)`, it kind of works, but not as I expected.

I want to the resulting alpha to be the minimum of the destination alpha (the alpha already on the screen) and the alpha of the brush.

The blending function `glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA)` does not work in cases like...

Lets say the screen (destination) has an alpha of 0.5. When the edge of the brush (where the brush's alpha is 1) touches this pixel, the resulting pixel's alpha should remain 0.5 (minimum of 1 and 0.5). But with the above blending function it would become (1 * 0.5 + 1 * 1), making it more opaque again.

What blending options shall I use to get a smooth erase brush? Is there any other approach I can take to solve it?